# validate ru- phone number with regular expression

Tags: regex

I need to create validation at phone number with format 8-XXX-XXX-XX-XX and can't write regular expression for it, I wrote something like this ^\d{1}-(\d{3}) \d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$ but it doesn't work. ( language Java)

Comment: it always startswith 8? `^8(?:-\d{3}){2}(?:-\d{2}){2}$`

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex like below.

```
string.matches("8(?:-\\d{3}){2}(?:-\\d{2}){2}");
```

Note that `matches` function won't require anchors.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uF3pF4/1)